# Laravel 5.1 Eager Loading Cannot do additional where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here but this code

```
$models = Model::with(['relationship' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereBetween('date', [$this->today->copy()->startOfDay(), $this->today->copy()->endOfDay()]);
    }])->where('status', 'active')->where('position', '!=', 'dev')->where('status', '=', 'good')->get();
```

doesn't work as expected. It does eager load the relationship it exists in the object but the problem is I cant do something like this

```
foreach($models as $model)
    {
        echo $model->relationship->where('status', '=', 'somestatus')->count() . '<br>';
    }
```

it returns 0 but when I check in collection it is not 0. Do you guys know why does this code not work? Thank you guys.

Comment: The  `where` in the `foreach` loop will be done on the collection rather than the database since the model relationship has been eagerly loaded.

Comment: Yes but it should count the right way. Because it returns the relationship with different statuses and i want to count only the ones who has the required status but it doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Try without `'='` in where statement. `$model->relationship->where('status', 'somestatus')->count()`. In documentation it only takes 2 parameters. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where

Comment: @devk still the same. the second parameter is the condition if the two given paramaters is =, !=, > or <. EDITED: IT WORKS IT JUST FINISHED LOADING.

Comment: @devk can you post it as an answer? So I can make it the correct answer

Comment: @KeannuAlforqueAtilano Happily :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `'='` (middle parameter) from your `->relationship->where('status', 'somestatus')`. Since you're doing it on a collection [it only takes 2 parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where).

So like this:

```
foreach($models as $model)
{
    echo $model->relationship->where('status', 'somestatus')->count() . '<br>';
}
```